# Custom dialog(Modal Dialog) should display half of the screen in nativescript angular2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I referred this [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/01/using-modal-dialogs-nativescript-angular-mobile-application/) and this [link](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/dialogs.html#custom-dialog)

when click on the floating action button, I'm using custom modal dialog to show the listview to half of the screen.

But it is taking full screen like below image:

[image]

I tried to set boolean variable fullScreen to `false` then also its showing full screen only.

**ts file:**

```
 public showModal() {

     console.log("showmod", "Test");

     let options = {
         context: {},
         fullscreen: false,
         viewContainerRef: this.vcRef
     };
     this.modal.showModal(ModalComponent, options).then(res => {
         console.log("ModRes :", ""+res);
     });
 }
```

**dialogs.d.ts: (node-modules/nativescript-angular/directives)**

```
import { ViewContainerRef, Type } from "@angular/core";
export interface ModalDialogOptions {
    context?: any;
    fullscreen?: boolean;
    viewContainerRef?: ViewContainerRef;
}
export declare class ModalDialogParams {
    context: any;
    closeCallback: (...args) => any;
    constructor(context: any, closeCallback: (...args) => any);
}
export declare class ModalDialogService {

    showModal(type: Type<any>, options: ModalDialogOptions): Promise<any>;
    private static showDialog(type, options, doneCallback, containerRef, resolver, parentPage, pageFactory);
}
export declare class ModalDialogHost {
    constructor();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the native behavior on iOS.

> By design on iPhone, a modal page appears only in fullscreen.

Noted [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages)